# NServiceBus Subscribe from v3.0 subscriber to v2.6 publisher

Tags: nservicebus, publish-subscribe

We have a v2.6 publisher and 2 consumers, one is 2.6 and the other is 3.0. The 3.0 subscribes is unable to subscribe messages. The publisher raises an exception when receiving subscription requests from the v3 subscriber:

`Could not extract message data. System.Xml.XmlException: Root element is missing.`

We think the exception raised because v3 sends subscription request messages without a body. (V2.6 subscriber sends messages that contains a body, hence the assumption). Is there any way  that will allow v3 to subscribe to v2.6 publisher?

Comment: Edited to include error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a confirmed bug in NServiceBus V3.0.0, can you upgrade to the latest [NServiceBus 3.2.2](http://particular.net/downloads) ?

I have confirmed that a V2.6 publisher works with a V3.2.2 subscriber.